# PatternLock temporary disable in jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using a third party library to emulate the 3x3 android pattern lock screen using js and jQuery.

repo: https://github.com/s-yadav/patternLock

emulator: http://ignitersworld.com/lab/patternLock.html#intro

I would like to add `disable()` and `enable()` functions to the `PatternLock.prototype`, in order to disable the user's ability to draw new patterns while a routine is running to save the pattern they drew previously. So the user would need to be able to see their pattern but not draw a new pattern until the routine is over and the lock is re-enabled.

What's the best way to do this? The built-in event handlers are anonymous functions so I shy away from using `.off()` and `.on()`. Adding the class `patt-hidden` still allows a new pattern to show up after it's drawn, just not while it is being drawn. Anyone know which direction to go, or have tried writing a disable method for this before?

Answer (score 0):

This is inelegant, but I was able to hack it by adding a global boolean `var disabled = false` to pattern.js, which was toggled in two helper functions enabled() and disable() in the PatternLock prototype. Then run a check at the beginning of each event handler, which exits if `disabled===true`. The most recent pattern selected stays visible but lock throws empty click events until re-enabled.

I would love to hear a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

patternLock 0.4.0+ now do have enable disable method in core.

To disable / enable you can use

```
var lock = patternLock('#patternHolder');
lock.disable();
lock.enable();
```